# Rails App, Elastic Beanstalk and REST API failure: (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

The main goal for my project is to build a rails app and REST API in rails and host on Amazon webservices such as elastic beanstalk with AmazonRDS to support. Then use API calls to allow for android and iOS apps to use the data through the API.

The step I'm on is deploying the rails app to elastic beanstalk, yet it fails. I'm using rails 3.2.13 and ruby 1.9.3, SQLite3 database, as well as 64bit linux Amazon ruby 1.9.3 for the deployment environment. I am following the instructions here to deploy a rails app to elastic beanstalk:
http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx2AK2MFX0QHRIO/Deploying-Ruby-Applications-to-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk-with-Git

Yet I keep coming up with this error: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cwvypf3neh754xs/AWSRailsErrors.PNG
(I apologize for the pictures but there was no other way to demonstrate the problem efficiently)

I have tried bundle update on SQLite3 as well as all gems for that matter, but it continues to list more.

I have been at it for a few days without any changes in errors, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

sqlite3 should only be used for development/test environments.  In your gemfile the sqlite3 gem should be under a seperate group like this:

```
group :test, :development do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

You can then add a seperate group for whatever database you want to use for your deployment, like mysql:

```
group :production do
   gem 'mysql2'
end
```

Also make sure to configure your database.yml file for the production database.

Comment: I simply wish to get the application running, so I would need to create an instance of AmazonRDS and put the credentials in the database.yml?

Comment: hmm.. It looks like EC2 can run sqlite3 but I don't know if beanstalk supports deploying to it.  I would suggest trying two things:

before deploying use these commands on EC2 to install the gem:
    yum install sqlite3
    yum install ruby-devel

You may also want to try skipping the migrations in beanstalk by setting RAILS_SKIP_MIGRATIONS to true.